# Why is the delete button on my application not working?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I made a delete button that's supposed to delete some entries from a model, but i keep getting an error that i'm not sure how to solve, I have a controller that has an IActionresult named deletelname, and everything seems logical but i just don't know why it's not working. If someone could look at the code and give me some feed back i would appreciate it very much.

The view:

```
 @model IEnumerable<Models.pinfo>
@using Models
@foreach (var s in Model){

<h1> @s.fname  @s.lname </h1> <h3> @s.comment </h3> <a class="GoDelete" href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="@s.lname">Delete</a>

   <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Deleting....</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Are you sure to Delete this Course?
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button id="btndelete" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

}

@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#btndelete").click(function () {
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                var id = $('#hfId').val();
                window.location.href = '@Url.Action("deletelname","Home")/'+id;
            });

            $(".GoDelete").click(function () {
                var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
                $('#hfId').val(id);
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            });

        });
    </script>


}
```

the Controller piece:

```
    public IActionResult deletelname(pinfo pinfo)
    {

        var fsname = db.pinfo;
        var lsname = db.pinfo;
        var csomment = db.pinfo;

        foreach (var fname in fsname)
        {
            db.Remove(fname);
        }

        foreach (var lname in lsname){
            db.Remove(lname);
        }

        return View("Contact", "Home");
    }
```

here is the error i get when i press the delete button:

[image: error]

Comment: Hello friend, it seems i have mistyped that, but now after fixing it, i am getting a totally different error in chrome, i would appriciate the help. The error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: pinfoId is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (Contact:77)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.js:4737)
    at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4549)

Comment: Just to clarify, what is the file name for the view code you show above?

Comment: its contact.cshtml

Answer (score 3):

The error message is because you are passing the string "Home" as the model for the view "Contact". The view is expecting an enumerable object of type Model.pinfo

try passing the pinfo object back out of the controller when rendering the view. I'm not sure that will do what you want but it seems to be what you are looking for.

```
    public IActionResult deletelname(pinfo pinfo)
    {

        var fsname = db.pinfo;
        var lsname = db.pinfo;
        var csomment = db.pinfo;

        foreach (var fname in fsname)
        {
            db.Remove(fname);
        }

        foreach (var lname in lsname){
            db.Remove(lname);
        }

        return Contact();
    }
```

Javascript is not correct either

```
$("#btndelete").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("deletelname","Home")',
        method: 'POST',
        data: { pinfo: $('#hfId').val() },
        success: function (response) {
            // this code gets run after the request is successful
            // based on the controller method that we have written, the response
            // should be all of the "Contact" view html re-rendered.
            console.log(response);

            //if there is an error you will probably not want to close the modal
            // so only close if it is successful
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        },
        error: function (response) {
            //runs if there is an error
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @Dr.MaxCox forgot that the model was expecting an enumerable not an instance of the model. I updated my answer.

Comment: hey thanks alot for the help, it deletes it but when i refresh the page, the data is back on...

Comment: That makes sense, because I'm having you pass back the model that you removed from the database. While it is being removed from the database, you are not actually changing the model. How do you originally show the view? can you post the controller method?

Comment: yes of course:

        public IActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Your contact page.";

            var liste = db.pinfo.ToList();


            return View(liste); 
        }

Comment: try it now. I changed the controller method to use the database call you made to originally populate. I think that should work.

Comment: nope now it doesn't delete anything, though the weird thing is that the url changes to http://localhost:5000/Home/deletelname/undefined

Comment: What if you return the other controller method? See changed code.

Comment: nope. Now the framwork thinks deletelname is a view and claims it can't be found :(

Comment: Ah that is because your javascript isn't quite right. I posted some changes. See if that works.

Comment: nope, doesn't work either, nothing happens when delete button is pressed :( this is so frustrating for me as a beginner with such a complex framework

Comment: I understand the frustration. I'm just realizing I lead you astray with my last comment and edit. I don't know if you have any experience using Ajax, but I think that is the way you should go. I'll give you a rough outline of what that might be in just a second

Comment: i have some experience in ajax, i would appreciate the help man.

Comment: I added some code that should make an ajax request, you might have to mess around with the parameters a bit. See the jquery docs http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. I'm not sure that it will make it to your controller method because I just passed the id along to the pinfo object in the request. that might blow up. I wish you luck as you proceed!

Comment: thanks for the help bro, im sure ill be able to fix this soon, have a nice day.